# Getting error "Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going slightly mad with this. Why does this script works inside SE but does not work inside JSFiddle???

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myControllers']);

var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.petameters = 10;
    $scope.lightyears = $scope.petameters / 9.460730472580800;
    $scope.parsecs = $scope.lightyears / 3.2616;
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        Petameters:<input type="text" ng-model="petameters"><br/>
          Light years:<input type="text" ng-model="lightyears"><br/>
          Parsecs:<input type="text" ng-model="parsecs"><br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/wr7kvsy9/5/

Code is copy pasted. In JSFiddle version it does not show any values in cells.

Also it throws an exception `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` with message `Failed to instantiate module {0} due to:\n{1}"` with placeholders are not set...

Comment: in jsfiddle used minified version and provided link where error message _Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:_ and then stacktrace

Comment: This is because JSFiddle by default puts your javascript code into a `onLoad` event, and by that time the Angularjs library has loaded and tried to parse everything, but your module code has yet to run so it cannot find it. https://jsfiddle.net/fo355d9b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error in jsfiddle settings. Scripts executed onLoad event

[image]

You should change it, for example, to `"no wrap - in <head>"`

[image]

and all work fine

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wr7kvsy9/8/)